# "select count()" is very slow

Tags: vb.net, networking, foxpro

I have a database with 1,000,000 records and a query like this:

```
select count(code) from table1
```

It works well on the local system but becomes very slow on the network. Other queries like `select * from table` execute quickly, but `select count(code) from table1` is very slow. I can't change the database's structure. My database is Foxpro and I use VB.NET.

Is there a solution?

**Edit:** Should I write code like this?

```
dim ds as new dataset
dim da as new datadapter("select count(*) from table ", connection)
da.fill(ds,"tbl1")
```

Then how can I get `select count(code) from table1` from the dataset?

Or do I have to use LINQ?

**Edit 2:** I mean the comparison between `select count(*)` and `select count(code)`.
What is the solution?

Comment: As has been said already, when you need to clarify your question, please edit it rather than posting answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It will be faster to do

```
select count(*) from table1
```

then to use `count(code)`.

Comment: Why? That seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: @David: Basically, `count(*)` is treated as a special case: It just counts the row without retrieving any data.  `count(code)` retrieves the column just to count it.

Answer (score 0):

The select count(code) selects the column 'code' from the table, and then counts them, but select * just selects them, but does not do the count. So if you are comparing these two then logically select * is fast.

For my table which has more than 1,000,000 records the execution time is:

select * = 0.9818625

select count(column_name) = 1.571275